# Create PIL image from memory stream provided by C library

Tags: python

I have a char pointer to png data provided by a `c` library.
How do I create a image in python from this data in memory.
The `c` function looks like this:

```
char *getImage(int *imgSize);
```

In Python I got the char* as follows:

```
imSize = c_int()
img = c_char_p()
img = c_char_p(my_c_api.getImage(byref(imSize)))
```

The `char*` is returned into the img variable and the size of the image in bytes is returned in the `imSize` variable.

When executing the following python script:

```
im = Image.frombuffer("RGBA", (400,400),  img.value, 'raw', "RGBA", 0, 1)
```

I get a `ValueError: buffer is not large enough` error.
I suspect the img variable in the `frombuffer` call.
What do I have to do with the img variable, to pass the image data correctly to the `frombuffer` call?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to put the data in a `StringIO` instance and have PIL parse the data from that.

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

imgfile = StringIO(img.value)
im = Image.open(imgfile)
```

`.frombuffer` assumes raw image data, not PNG-encoded data. The `StringIO` object provides a file-like object to wrap your data in, so PIL can work with it.

Comment: Using the above i get the following error
 _raise IOError("cannot identify image file")_

The length of the image buffer is 13984 bytes.
When executing _len(img.value)_ the answer is 8 bytes, it looks like not all the 13984 bytes ends up in the imgfile with the _StringIO(img.value)_ command, thus the _IOError("cannot identify image file")_

Please help, i need to create the png image in python from the data buffer returned from the c api.

Comment: Apologies, I have no idea how your C API works; get the whole buffer as a string first, before passing it into the StringIO instance.

Comment: Also, the identification would use the first set of bytes from the file, bytes missing at the end I would expect to give a different error (but I am not certain).